# Edited /etc/cron.d/anacron, changes are immediately in effect?

Tags: debian, cron

After editing `/etc/cron.d/anacron` and saving the file, are the changes immediately acknowledged by cron? Or do I need to run a command to tell cron to reload `/etc/cron.d/anacron`?

Comment: Yes immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They work immediately after saving